# Numpy reshape 3D to 2D column wise

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a list of df,the objective is to reshape the df_convert_array into 2D array.

The below snippet does fulfill the objective

```
alist_df=[pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(4,2))) for _ in range (3)]
arr=np.array(alist_df)
arr_opt=np.array([narr.T.reshape(-1) for narr in arr])
```

But, the proposed solution require to first transpose and reshape each array in the list.

I thought, the process can be simplified simply as below

```
arr_opt=arr.T.reshape(3,-1)
```

However, the output is not as I expect.

May I know how to avoid the use of list-comprehension as describe above?

Remark: Output should be in the form of 2D numpy array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

running your code:

```
In [435]: import pandas as pd
In [436]: alist_df=[pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(4,2))) for _ in ran
     ...: ge (3)]
     ...: arr=np.array(alist_df)
In [437]: arr
Out[437]: 
array([[[34, 87],
        [25, 46],
        [52, 64],
        [76, 73]],

       [[18,  4],
        [ 7,  3],
        [48, 76],
        [37, 48]],

       [[82, 51],
        [49, 71],
        [90, 49],
        [29,  3]]])
In [438]: arr.shape
Out[438]: (3, 4, 2)
```

I wish you'd at least given the shape info.

```
In [439]: arr_opt=np.array([narr.T.reshape(-1) for narr in arr])
In [440]: arr_opt
Out[440]: 
array([[34, 25, 52, 76, 87, 46, 64, 73],
       [18,  7, 48, 37,  4,  3, 76, 48],
       [82, 49, 90, 29, 51, 71, 49,  3]])
In [441]: arr_opt.shape
Out[441]: (3, 8)
```

It would also have been nice to see the desired output. We shouldn't have to run the code samples to make sense of what's happening.  That said, it's good that you provided working code.

But comparing the two arrays lets me see that you want to join values column wise within the subblocks.  Let's first do a transpose with parameters:

```
In [442]: arr.transpose(0,2,1)
Out[442]: 
array([[[34, 25, 52, 76],
        [87, 46, 64, 73]],

       [[18,  7, 48, 37],
        [ 4,  3, 76, 48]],

       [[82, 49, 90, 29],
        [51, 71, 49,  3]]])
```

That's equivalent to doing `narr.T`.  The rest is a trivial reshape.

```
In [443]: arr.transpose(0,2,1).reshape(3,8)
Out[443]: 
array([[34, 25, 52, 76, 87, 46, 64, 73],
       [18,  7, 48, 37,  4,  3, 76, 48],
       [82, 49, 90, 29, 51, 71, 49,  3]])
```

And just as a guess lets see what happens with a reshape using order

```
In [444]: arr.reshape(3,8,order='F')
Out[444]: 
array([[34, 25, 52, 76, 87, 46, 64, 73],
       [18,  7, 48, 37,  4,  3, 76, 48],
       [82, 49, 90, 29, 51, 71, 49,  3]])
```

I haven't use `order` with 3d arrays, so wasn't sure what it would do with the first dimension.  For a 2d array, transpose is the equivalent of a `order='F'` reshape.

Answer (score 1):

You can also transpose the array, reshape, and then transpose back:

```
arr_opt = np.reshape(arr.T, (arr.shape[2]*arr.shape[1], -1)).T
```

(the references to `arr.shape` are in case you don't know ahead of time what the dimensions of your dataframes are)

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, the transpose operation will permute all three axes before the final reshape, whereas in your first example, only the second two axes are effectively permuted.

Try `arr_opt = arr.transpose((0,2,1)).reshape((3,-1))`

Comment: Thanks for dropping by, but it seems the compiler return an error `ValueError: axes don't match array`

Comment: I edited my answer. Thank you for the help.